# How can I make an div span the entire width of my screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im making a little project and I just cant seem to get my css right... I need my header div(I used a regular div instead of an actual header because I wanted everything in the body). I want the blue header span my entire screen, but I just dont know how. I tried somethings with margin and padding but thats it.

Also I tried getting those buttons to the bottom of the Div, but just cant seem to get it right...

SCREENSHOT: http://prntscr.com/9slfw2
Description: See my website here

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.page-header{
    background-color: #0094ff;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: block
}


.panel, .list-group-item, .btn {
    border-color: #0094ff;
}

#btnRegister {
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.input-group-addon {
    min-width: 40px;
}

legend.scheduler-border {
    width:inherit;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <div class="item active">
            <img class="c_img" src="~/Images/chevy.jpg" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                    <p style="background-color:#428bca;">Om gemakkelijk met Rent-a-Car contact op te nemen kunt u ook bellen!</p>
                    <p style="background-color:#428bca;">Tel: 0534891034, Adres: Vuurnatieweg 69420</p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="~/Home/Contact" >Klik hier voor meer contact informatie!</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <div class="item">
            <img class="c_img" src="~/Images/42-RT-76.jpg" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
                    <p style="background-color:#428bca;">Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
                    <p style="background-color:#428bca;"><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
    <div id="carouselButtons">
        <button id="playButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </button>
        <button id="pauseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel({
        interval:5000,
        pause: "false"
    });
    $('#playButton').click(function () {
        $('#homeCarousel').carousel('cycle');
    });
    $('#pauseButton').click(function () {
        $('#homeCarousel').carousel('pause');
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT: HTML code and .. I am using Bootstrap, just so you know

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: 100%;` to your `.page-header` class style?

Comment: Post a complete code example please. Not just two CSS rules.

Comment: Try adding `display: block` to your css.

Comment: Yea.. ive tried the 100% percent

Comment: display: block doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using Bootstrap, as indicated by the classes in your HTML and your clarifying edit. Bootstrap adds its own styling (obviously).

In particular, the `.container` class has padding, margins, and a fixed width that will prevent your layout from spanning the full screen. If you're doing things correctly, your `.row` `<div>` tag is in a container.

**You have two options to fix this:**

1. Use [`.container-fluid`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) instead of `.container`**

   This is the preferred option.
2. Override the default `.container` CSS rules

   To override it, add rules for `.container`, like so:

   ```
   .container {
       padding-left: 0px;
       padding-right: 0px;
       margin-right: 0px;
       margin-left: 0px;
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```

   Here's [**a sample with Bootstrap's default CSS**](http://codepen.io/edcottrell/pen/LGeZGB) and [**one with the `.container` tweaks above**](http://codepen.io/edcottrell/pen/MKreyp).

   Note: if you only want to override the one `.container`, just give it its own class or id and use an appropriate selector instead of `.container` in your CSS.

Comment: It did pull my entire website to the left, but now i still have a big white space to the right of my website, How can I make that everything but my header remains in the same position. (centered)

Comment: I'm a newcomer to html and this saved me hours. The devil is buried in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bootstrap, you can use .container-fluid instead of .container to get a full-width container.

Also, you seem to have mixed head (not in body) with header (in body).
More on the header tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header

Answer (score -1):

Your code does span

Have a look here [Demo](http://jsbin.com/kekigo/edit?html,css)

Comment: Yeah thats why im on here haha... it doesnt on my screen, see my screenshot